# PIC16F877A not working with 4MHz oscillator

Tags: pic, oscillator, pic16f877a

I was trying to do a LED flashing program, but the LED didn't turned on. I tried also with a program to just light the LED, but it didn't work either. I searched and one solution says to change the config bits, but also tried it and didn't work.

This is the XC8 code of the LED on program:

```c
#include <xc.h>
void main(void) {
  TRISA = 0;
  while(true) {
    RA0 = 1;
  }
}
```

Config bits are:

```
WDT FALSE
PWRT TRUE
BOR FALSE
LVP FALSE
CPD TRUE
WRT FALSE
CP TRUE
```

I'm runnng it without capacitors on the oscillator, but it also didn't work with `47pF` capacitors.
The source of voltage is an Arduino Mega, with the `5V` and `GND` pins.
`MCLR` is connected to `5V` with a `10k resistor`

Comment: What do you mean the pic didn’t run it? Do you mean the LED didn’t turn on? This is not the same. Stick a multimeter on the RA0 pin. Also, are you sure the LED is active high. Try putting RA0 = 0.

Comment: CONFIG bits also contain **FOSC1** and **FOSC0**. Of the four selections possible, a 4 MHz crystal requires FOSC0=high and FOSC1=low. This is oscillator "XT" mode. And have you tied **not_MCLR** pin to logic high? If it is low, nothing runs.

Comment: Which compiler? How did you set the config bits? What did you do with the MCLR pin?

Comment: @user110971 Thank you. RA0 has an output of 0.2V. How can I increase it?

Comment: 1. What model of programmer / flash loader are you using?
2. Do your IDE / any other software report that the firmware is loading successfully?

Comment: @Arseniy Im using DIY K150, and yes, it says "Program sucessful"

Comment: @glen_geek How can I define those config bits?

Comment: Saul, have never used XC8, but apparently you can include a line: **#pragma config FOSC = ECH**, which would allow an external oscillator to drive the PIC16F877 **OSC1** pin with a square wave between 4 - 20 MHz. You'll have to read XC8 docs to see what to substitute for **ECH**. BTW: you can use either **XT** or **HS** internal crystal oscillator, with C1=15pf, C2=15pf for the crystal capacitors (@ 4 MHz). XC8 also lets you see config bit settings in this window: Window>Target Memory Views>Configuration Bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are not turn off the ADC.

I mean when this MCU starts the ADCON1 register set to 00h. And bits PCFG3:PCFG0 are also 0000b. Thus, according the table on the pg.130 of the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39582b.pdf) all  pins in the port0 are analog inputs. This table tell us that we need set bits PCFG3:PCFG0 on 011Xb to use the port0 as digital input-output.

Try to add

```
ADCON1 = 6;
```

before

```
TRISA = 0;
```

Comment: With those changes, the most that I get from RA0 is 0.3V

Comment: Hmm. Try to use other pin or other port. Will the result change?
Can you use an assembler in your IDE? Which IDE do you use?
Do you have the Proteus-II to simulate your firmware?

Comment: Now it works! But only when I touch the USB port. I thik it's because the static.

Comment: Its the static. I putted the protoboard and the arduino on a plastic table and it worked, but when i touched the arduino it stopped